# Web scrape excel file in different date

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm a newbie to beautiful soup. Can anyone suggest how to scrape the excel file for the past 14 days? My understanding is to loop over the date and save the file. Thanks

https://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur/sbn.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur/sbn.asp")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
```

Now we will find data inside table using `find` method and use `find_all` to get all `td` tags and append data to list `lst`.

```
main_data=soup.find("table").find_all("td")
lst=[]
for data in main_data:
    try:
        url=data.find("a").get('href')[1:]
        main_url="https://www.hkexnews.hk/reports/sharerepur"+url
        lst.append(main_url)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Now iterate through `lst` and call individual URL to download data to excel file.

```
for url in range(len(lst)):
    resp=requests.get(lst[url])
    output = open(f'test_{url}.xls', 'wb')
    output.write(resp.content)
    output.close()
    print(url)
```

Image: (File being created in Local)

[image]